# PL/SQL float addition

Tags: plsql, addition

I would like to add a value to a float but it's not working.

I have a float, like 3.14 and I want to add 0.005 but I get 3.14.

The code :

```
create or replace package pck_test is

PROCEDURE ArrondiGeo(coord_x IN FLOAT,coord_y IN FLOAT,temp_x OUT FLOAT);

end pck_test;
/

create or replace package body pck_test is


    PROCEDURE ArrondiGeo(coord_x IN FLOAT,coord_y IN FLOAT,temp_x OUT FLOAT,temp_y OUT FLOAT)
    IS
        tp_x FLOAT;
    BEGIN
        tp_x := mod(coord_x*10000,10);

        if(tp_x>50)
        then
            if(tp_x>75)
            then
                temp_x:=trunc(coord_x,2);
                temp_x:=temp_x+0.01;
            else
                temp_x:=trunc(coord_x,2);
                temp_x:=temp_x+0.005;
            end if;
        else
            if(tp_x>25)
            then
                temp_x:=trunc(coord_x,2);
                temp_x:=temp_x+0.005;
            else
                temp_x:=trunc(coord_x,2);
            end if;
        end if;


    END;
END pck_test;
/
```

Does anyone know why it's not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you are consistent in the sample code, maybe are you mixing `FLOAT` and `BINARY_FLOAT` in the rest of your program.

- `FLOAT` is a subtype of `NUMBER` with up to 38 digits precision. `0.005` is a literal *float*.
- `BINARY_FLOAT` is an [IEEE 754 floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats) with roughly speaking 7 decimal digits of precision. `0.005f` would be a literal *binary_float*.

See this example:

```
declare
  w float :=  3.14;
  x float :=  3.14*100000;
  y binary_float :=  3.14;
  z binary_float :=  3.14*100000;
begin
  w := w + 0.005;
  x := x + 0.005;
  y := y + 0.005f;
  z := z + 0.005f;

  dbms_output.put_line(w);
  dbms_output.put_line(x);
  dbms_output.put_line(y);
  dbms_output.put_line(z);
end;
```

Producing:

```
3.145
314000.005
3.14500022E+000
3.14E+005
```

Comment: Learnt that little something that makes your day today :-)